# Apache Netbeans 10 binaries not working

Tags: high-sierra, java, apache, ide

I have recently downloaded the Apache Netbeans 10 binaries from the [Apache Netbeans (Incubating) site](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb100/nb100.html). I extracted the zip file to /Application/netbeans/. But when I try to run `/Application/netbeans/bin/netbeans` I get the an error in the terminal: `Unknown option: n` follow by the help message. What I'm missing here? I'm running `java version "11.0.2"`. Please for your help.

Comment: This is open source, did you follow the instructions in the ReadMe?  Have you raised an issue on their [issues site](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS/issues/)?

Comment: Yes, `To start the IDE (Solaris OS or Linux):
Type at the command prompt: /netbeans-install-directory/bin/netbeans
 ` from the ReadMe file

Comment: So those directions will work on macOS?

Comment: Yes, I also watch a video tutorial on Youtube and the above command works just fine on macOS